# significance of Hartley's Fmax test using only N and SD in R

Tags: r, variance

How can I calculate the significance of the Hartley's Fmax test in R using only the Ns and SDs with data that have different Ns?

For example, for only 2 groups:

```
n1 <- 50
sd1 <- 23.7
n2 <- 70
sd2 <- 130.4
```

Comment: Are these the *only* sds?  If not, they will need to be the extreme sds and, at a minimum, you will also need to know how many groups are involved and what each of those group sizes is.

Comment: @whuber, I don't understand what you mean. `sd1` is the standard deviation of group 1 with `n1`, whereas `sd2` is the standard deviation of group 2 with `n2`. Can't Hartley's Fmax test for differences in variances when only sd and n is known?

Comment: Hartley's test is intended for *many* groups, not just two (which is a special example and easy to deal with).

Comment: OK, thanks. So I can still use Hartley's test even if I only have 2 groups, right? Do you know a package that will allow me to run this test, or do I need to calculate it manually?

Comment: With only two groups, you're running a standard F test.  The whole point to Hartley's test is to cope with the complications of three or more groups.  Its disadvantage -- and why it is (or should be) rarely used -- is that it's very sensitive to the Normality assumption.  Even with two groups the result is fairly sensitive to that assumption.  But if the n's and sd's are all you have, then go for it.